# ManagedBean, el cambio del atributo no persiste

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Saludos.

Llamo a un método de un bean para que añada un elemento a un private `arrayList`. Se añade correctamente, pero cuando vuelvo a llamarlo de nuevo (ajax) para añadir un segundo elemento el `arrayList` está vacío. Se cambia pero no persiste.

Supongo que no tiene nada que ver, pero es un drap and drop datatable

Comment: ¿Cuál es el `scope` del controlador?

Comment: Arreglado. Había que cambiar a sesión